# If $L = L(M)$ then $L$ is a subset of $L(M)$ and $L(M)$ is a subset of $L$

Tags: terminology, sets

If $L = L(M)$ then $L$ is a subset of $L(M)$ and $L(M)$ is a subset of $L$.

Can anyone clarify what does this mean?

Comment: Similarly, if L(M1) = L(M2) then L(M1) is a subset of L(M2) and L(M2) is a subset of L(M1).

Comment: $L$ is in this context some defined language, $M$ is some machine, and by $L(M)$, we mean the language that $M$ recognizes (or defines).  By set theoretic definitions, $L = L(M)$ precisely when both $L \subseteq L(M)$ and $L \supseteq L(M)$.  So to prove that $L=L(M)$, you show that if $x \in L$ then $x \in L(M)$ and vice versa, if $y \in L(M)$ then $y \in L$.  This means that you need to show that for any element $x$, $x \in L$ if and only if $x \in L(M)$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is just a set-theoretical equality. Two sets are equal precisely when they are included in one another: $A = B$ iff $A\subseteq B$ and $B\subseteq A$. The notation is applied in the context of languages of automata. In order to show an automaton $M$ defines language $L$, you have to show it accepts all strings from $L$, and no more than those strings.

Basic, when doing automata and language theory, I am afraid.

Comment: I guess u are right